|∆v| = ∆v in circular motion?


Why is ∆v = |∆v|? How can a vector quantity equal a scalar quantity? Also (referring to the 2nd image) how can I see from the figure that ∆v = |∆v| (= v∆θ)?
For reference: Physical Chemistry: A Molecular Approach, McQuarrie (problem 1-41).
Or (images originated from there): Student Solutions Manual for Physical Chemistry: A Molecular Approach (problem 1-41).

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Note the use of a bolded $v$ in their expression. So they aren't equating a scalar with a vector. As to how to make sense from the figured, I'm not falling myself. I'd express the circle as parameterized x,y in time then take the relevant derivatives.

@TurlocTheRed so the non-bolded ∆v should just mean the difference in speed without directly referring to a vector, while |∆v| (bolded) is the magnitude of a vector? But if ∆v isn't a vector, for me it doesn't make sense to talk about a velocity change, because in this problem the whole change in the velocity comes from the direction change of the velocity vector, the magnitude stays the same.

The text uses $\Delta v$ for the length of a change of the vector $\vec v$, so it can be anything between 0 and $2v$, where $v$ is the scalar (and for a regular circular motion) constant speed. So $\Delta v$ is defined (!) that way and not a difference in the scalar $v$.

The symbol $\mathbf v$ represents a vector in the material you are reading.
In the same place, the symbol $v$ represents a scalar.
The difference is subtle, but these two letters are printed in different fonts and are different objects.
The more complicated part is $\Delta v$.
Normally this expression would be the difference between the "after" and "before" values of the scalar $v$,
but that interpretation makes no sense in this context,
because $v$ is a constant but $\Delta v$ is clearly intended to be non-zero.
The only interpretation I can see that makes sense is that $\Delta v$ is meant to be read as a single symbol, and that it is defined by the equation
$$ \Delta v = \lvert\Delta\mathbf v\rvert. $$
So the reason why that equation is true is because that's how $\Delta v$ is defined.
Frankly, I think this is a foolish definition.
Because the expression $\Delta v$ has another, more usual interpretation in a context like this, the definition introduces ambiguity into the notation. Moreover, $\Delta v$ barely takes less space on the page than
$\lvert\Delta\mathbf v\rvert$,
so it's a waste of the reader's time and brain power to introduce this definition (even more so due to the ambiguity of the notation).
Then again, someone who couldn't be bothered to make it clear which came first, $\mathbf r_1$ or $\mathbf r_2$ (that is, whether we're going around the circle clockwise or counterclockwise), probably wouldn't be much concerned with clarity and freedom from ambiguity in notation.
As for the reason why
$$ \lvert\Delta\mathbf v\rvert \approx v \Delta\theta, $$
(note, that's $\approx$, not $=$),
when the position is $\mathbf r_2$ the velocity is $\mathbf v_2$ with magnitude $v$ in the direction tangent to the circle at $\mathbf r_2$,
and when the position is $\mathbf r_1$ the velocity is $\mathbf v_1$ with magnitude $v$ in the direction tangent to the circle at $\mathbf r_1$.
During the transition from $\mathbf r_2$ to $\mathbf r_1$
(or vice versa, whichever the author had in mind),
the velocity vector changes from $\mathbf v_2$ to $\mathbf v_1$ (or vice versa).
Since these two vectors both have magnitude $v$ and the angle between them is $\Delta\theta$, the magnitude of their difference, $\lvert\Delta\mathbf v\rvert$, is approximately
$v \Delta\theta$ for the same reason that
$\lvert\Delta\mathbf r\rvert$ is approximately $r \Delta\theta$.

Thank you! That really helped me ^^ The problem originates from Physical Chemistry: A Molecular Approach, McQuarrie (Problem 1-41). The images I made came from Student Solutions Manual for Physical Chemistry: A Molecular Approach which is the exact same problem just with the solution attached (which I didn't find very detailed here lol).

Ah, not a math textbook. Technically not even a textbook, although a solutions manual ought to at least try to explain things. ... I just noticed that the figure on page 16, which is supposed to be "in analogy to Figure 1.12", is actually identical to Figure 1.12 -- not just the same shape, but the same labels. If the figure were actually expressed in terms of velocity, it would have $\mathbf v$ instead of $\mathbf r$ and at the top it would say $\lvert\Delta\mathbf v\rvert \approx v \Delta\theta$. Someone messed up.
